# Add a Second Menu to a theme that only support 1 menu

Tags: php, functions, themes, templates

I am no programmer but I can usually work stuff like this out when I read the code.

I have a theme called Infinity which only supports 1 menu. I know how to do CSS etc but I can't find how I would a second menu. In fact it doesn't have to be a custom menu but just the pages. Can anyone tell me how to do this? An excerpt of the code is below which appears to load the menu:

```
<div class="container_main">
```

```
<div class="container_12_head">
<?php get_template_part( 'custom', 'header' ); ?>

<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
  <div class="container_head_menu_wrap">
  <div class="container_12_head">
  <?php get_template_part( 'primary', 'menu' ); ?>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This code is in the header.php. I search for primary primary-menu.php and found this in it:

```
<?php
/** Primary Menu Callback */
function infinity_primary_menu_cb() {
    wp_page_menu();      
}
?>
<div class="grid_8 alpha">
  <div class="menu1">
    <div class="menu1-data">
      <?php
      if ( has_nav_menu( 'infinity-primary-menu' ) ):

        $args = array(

            'container' => 'div', 
            'container_class' => 'primary-container', 
            'theme_location' => 'infinity-primary-menu',
            'menu_class' => 'sf-menu1',
            'depth' => 0,
            'fallback_cb' => 'infinity_primary_menu_cb'

        );

        wp_nav_menu( $args );

      else:

        infinity_primary_menu_cb(); 

      endif;
      ?>
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
  </div>  <!-- end .menu1 --> 
</div>
```

Any help?

EDIT: Update. Functions page pasted below

```
<?php
/** Load the Core Files */
require_once( trailingslashit( get_template_directory() ) . 'lib/init.php' );
new Infinity();

/** Do theme setup on the 'after_setup_theme' hook. */
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'infinity_theme_setup' );

/** Theme setup function. */
function infinity_theme_setup() {

    /** Add theme support for core framework features. */
    add_theme_support( 'infinity-core-menus', array( 'infinity-primary-menu' ) );
    add_theme_support( 'infinity-core-sidebars', array( 'infinity-primary-sidebar' ) );
    add_theme_support( 'infinity-core-featured-image' );
    add_theme_support( 'infinity-core-custom-header' );

    /** Add theme support for WordPress features. */
    add_theme_support( 'automatic-feed-links' );
    add_theme_support( 'custom-background', array( 'default-color' => 'fafafa' ) );

    /** Set content width. */
    infinity_set_content_width( 600 );

    /** Add custom image sizes. */
    add_action( 'init', 'infinity_add_image_sizes' );   

}

/** Adds custom image sizes */
function infinity_add_image_sizes() {
    add_image_size( 'featured', 200, 200, true );
}
?>
```

Menu code below

```
function infinity_register_menus() {

    /** Get theme-supported menus. */
    $menus = get_theme_support( 'infinity-core-menus' );

    /** If there is no array of menus IDs, return. */
    if ( !is_array( $menus[0] ) ) {
        return;
    }

    /* Register the 'primary' menu. */
    if ( in_array( 'infinity-primary-menu', $menus[0] ) ) {
        register_nav_menu( 'infinity-primary-menu', __( 'Infinity Primary Menu', 'infinity' ) );
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding custom menu position to your wordpress theme is fairly simple.
This is usually done this way:

**1. Announcing the desired menu positions (in function.php):**

```
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menus' );

function register_my_menus() {
    register_nav_menus(
        array(
            'first-menu' => __( 'First Menu' ),
            'second-menu' => __( 'Second Menu' ),
            'third-menu' => __( 'Third Menu' )
        )
    );
}
```

.

**2. Embedding them in desired place in your theme:**

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'first-menu' ) ); ?>
```

.

In Your case & since you already have one custom menu position you first need to find in your functions.php where the current menu was defined and add another one as shown in the above example.

Hope this helps,
sagive.

EDITED (REPLACE THE EXISTING CODE IN YOUR MENU CODE):

```
function infinity_register_menus() {

    /** Get theme-supported menus. */
    $menus = get_theme_support( 'infinity-core-menus' );

    /** If there is no array of menus IDs, return. */
    if ( !is_array( $menus[0] ) ) {
        return;
    }

    /* Register the 'primary' menu. */
    if ( in_array( 'infinity-primary-menu', $menus[0] ) ) {
        register_nav_menu( 
            array(
                'infinity-primary-menu' => __( 'Infinity Primary Menu', 'infinity' ),
                'secondary-menu' => __( 'Secondary Primary Menu', 'infinity' )
            )
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: See my update above. I have posted the functions.php

Comment: The file that deals with menus isnt being included so it is probebaly hooked in some othere file. can you pastebin this file lib/init.php ??

Comment: cool, I see where you are going now. I opened the init file and found it referenced a menu.php file. After opening this I found how it was registering the menus. Code is pasted above. Can you ammend the code to add the second menu please?

Comment: This requires some testing since this is not the default structure... are you sure you dont have a way to create a new menu position in the backend? anyhow i have added a testing code... try it and let me know the result.

Comment: that didn't do anything at all. I don't care if there is another method, I just need to add a second many which displays pages (not posts). If you can think of another way that will be fine.

Comment: apologies... try revised code (changes 1 charachter..) - also what do you mean did nothing? did you wen inside your menus and checked for another location?

Comment: When I used your original code nothing happened at all, no errors and no addtional menu. When I now use your modified code it errors saying Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in /themes/infinity/lib/functions/menus.php on line 28 which is the line we added.

isn;t it because we have declared a new function of second-primary?? In the other pages (shown above) they reference infinity-primary-menu but they wont reference secondary?

Comment: sorry, i said this would require some testing since i lack access to the actuall files... i have revised my answer... awaiting results.

Comment: New Error says:

Warning: Missing argument 2 for register_nav_menu(), called in /home/greatwhi/public_html/wp-content/themes/infinity/lib/functions/menus.php on line 30 and defined in /home/greatwhi/public_html/wp-includes/nav-menu.php on line 106

Warning: Illegal offset type in /home/greatwhi/public_html/wp-includes/nav-menu.php on line 107

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/greatwhi/public_html/wp-includes/nav-menu.php:106) in /home/greatwhi/public_html/wp-includes/option.php on line 563

Comment: lol i just answered my own question. I found what it was. The code was regsiter_nav_menu. To add more than one menu the function is different; it has an S on the end "regsiter_nav_menus". I changed it to this and now i get no errors. it now displays 2 menus in the admin section. So far so good, now to get it displayed on main menu. Will test that and get back to you...

Comment: Ok so now I get no errors but it still displays only one menu on the front end. I suspect it has something to do with it not being called in the functions.php page? BEcause we created a new menu called secondary-menu, fucntions.php only calls the primary-menu...i think?

Comment: Managed to resolve this myself afterwards. Found where to add the code to display the menu on the front page. couldn't have done it without you so thanks a lot for all your help!

Comment: glad you got it working mate.